# IE browsers compatibility issue

Tags: browser

We have one web application which is hosted on WPS (webshere portlet server). We have two folder in our application, named as ie & css. (both these folders contain css files for IE and non IE browsers separately)

CSS file location for non IE browser:    --\theme\egmk\css\

CSS file location for IE browser:    --\egmk\ie\css\

When we access our portal using IE7 browser it picks up all the css files from “\egmk-\ie\css” folder but for IE8 it is picking from “egmk\css” folder which is causing big alignment and look & feel issue in IE8 browser. We are not able to identify the root cause for the issue with IE8 browser.

Below are the CCS files defined under  tag of Head.jsp file from where all the css is geting loaded. This is an exsisting file which is working fine for IE 7 & less.

```
<head><%--
--%><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"><%--
--%><meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"><%--
--%><meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript">history.go(1);</script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/cufon.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><style type="text/css">.cufon-canvas{text-indent:0!important;}@media screen,projection{.cufon-canvas{display:inline!important;display:inline-block!important;position:relative!important;vertical-align:middle!important;font-size:1px!important;line-height:1px!important;}.cufon-canvas .cufon-alt{display:-moz-inline-box!important;display:inline-block!important;width:0!important;height:0!important;overflow:hidden!important;}.cufon-canvas canvas{position:relative!important;}}@media print{.cufon-canvas{padding:0!important;}.cufon-canvas canvas{display:none!important;}.cufon-canvas .cufon-alt{display:inline!important;}}</style><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/Helvetica_Neue_LT_Std_Condensed_400.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/behaviors.js"/>'></script><%--

<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="600;URL=/wps/myportal">
--%><title><portal-fmt:text key="portal.title" bundle="nls.egmk-abn" /></title> <%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/menu.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/menufixer.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/compat.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/compatcalendar.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/calendar.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/calendar_new.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/print.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/overlib.css"/>'><%--
--%><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/jquery.autocomplete.css"/>'/><%--
--%><!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/ie7.css"/>'><![endif]--><%--
--%><![if ! IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/notie7.css"/>'><![endif]><%--
--%><!--[if IE 6]><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/jquery.bgiframe.js"/>'></script><![endif]--><%--
--%><!--[if IE 6]><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/ie6.js"/>'></script><![endif]--><%--
--%><style type="text/css">
/* add hover pseudoclass to elements */
* html body {
behavior: url('<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/csshover3.htc"/>')
}
</style><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/portletBarIcons.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/menu.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/menu-popup.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="js/preload.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar-en.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar-setup.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar_new.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar-setup_new.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><script type="text/javascript" src='<wps:urlFind file="calendar/js/calendar-en_new.js"/>'></script><%--
--%><!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/ie.css"/>'><![endif]--><%--
--%></head>
```

could you please look into the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

change first line of this

```
  
<!--[if lte IE 7]>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  
media="all" href='<wps:urlFindInTheme file="css/ie.css"/>  
'><![endif]-->
```

to

```
  
<!--[if gte IE 7]>  
or  
<!--[if IE 8]>
```

and point to the appropriate file. you pointed out the paths to the files, but i don't see any of them following the paths you mentioned.

Comment: the code you suggested is not working at all. in fact, i have removed the the whole line and the look and feel is still same as it used to be. and the attribute href='<wps:urlFindInTheme" will take till the path to specified folder and then append the file as "css/ie.css". I hope this would clear your doubt.

Comment: nope. have no clue what you mean. do you understand how conditional comments work? the two options i provided for you are targeting ie8 and up. they work, i use them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just put following code and your IE browser would open by default in defined compatible view.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Your site is working fine in IE7 so it is the good solution to make default compatible view of ie7 so you will not have any issue with upgraded IE versions.